# lintian reports shlib-calls-exit from flex generated source code when building a DEB package

Tags: flex-lexer, deb

If a [**DEB**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) package contains a shared library that was built from source code that was generated by [**flex**](https://github.com/westes/flex/) , [**/usr/bin/lintian**](http://lintian.debian.org) would report

[shlib-calls-exit](http://lintian.debian.org/tags/shlib-calls-exit.html)

because of the exit() call in the flex-generated function yy_fatal_error:

```
static void yy_fatal_error (yyconst char* msg )
{
        (void) fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", msg );
        exit( YY_EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

How can I modify the DEB package so that the lintian will stop reporting shlib-calls-exit?

The DEB package makes use of [**CMake**](http://cmake.org/) in its build script. The corresponding snippet of  CMake  source code is

```
flex_target(scanner lexer.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.c)
bison_target(parser parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.c) 
add_flex_bison_dependency(scanner parser)
add_library(parse-and-scan SHARED ${FLEX_scanner_OUTPUTS} ${BISON_parser_OUTPUT_SOURCE})
```

Information about the software versions:

- flex 2.5.35
- cmake 2.8.9
- lintian 2.5.10
- Linux distribution: **Debian Unstable (sid)**

About a week ago I posted a [similar question](http://lists.debian.org/debian-mentors/2012/11/msg00015.html) to the debian-mentors mailing list

The problem of having an exit() call in the flex generated source code has been [brought up](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29126320) on the flex-help mailing list, but that post rendered no answers.

Answer (score -1):

By replacing the exit() call with an abort() call **lintian** will no more report shlib-calls-exit. CMake could handle this replacement by reading the file **lexer.c** into a string, then doing text replacement, and then writing the string to the new file  **lexer_replaced.c** (an arbitrary filename).

```
flex_target(scanner lexer.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.c)
bison_target(parser parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.c) 
add_flex_bison_dependency(scanner parser)
set(replaced_file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer_replaced.c)
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/replace_exit_with_abort.cmake "
  file(READ ${FLEX_scanner_OUTPUTS} var1)
  string(REPLACE \"exit\\( YY_EXIT_FAILURE \\);\" \"abort();\" var2 \"\${var1}\")
  file(WRITE ${replaced_file} \"\${var2}\")
")
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${replaced_file}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} 
  ARGS -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/replace_exit_with_abort.cmake
  DEPENDS ${FLEX_scanner_OUTPUTS}
)
add_library(parse-and-scan SHARED ${replaced_file} ${BISON_parser_OUTPUT_SOURCE})
```

I think this is a workable solution, but the best solution in the long run would be to modify the program **flex** to always return from its functions instead of sometimes using exit() calls. If an error condition occurs a flex function would then pass this information to the caller by using a different return value.